# Linq where expressions as values to add

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5

I have a question about formatting LINQ query

I have the same query with different where options

For example:

```
var result = context.table.Include(x => x.table2).Where(q => q1);
```

The query is the same but in different situations I have different where expressions like q1,q2,q3

Can I configure the q objects separately and use it in the query like

```
var q1 = (q => q.x == "something");
var q2 = (q => q.x == "something2");
var q3 = (q => q.x == "something3");

var qx;
if(x)
{
    qx = q1;
}
if(y)
{
    qx = q2;
}

var result = context.table.Include(x => x.table2).Where(q => qx);
```

Comment: Why not try it out? Basically you can do this, however you have to declare `qx` **outside** the if-statements.

Comment: Why not just assign the value of the string?

Comment: Why not put them all as `OR` condition

Comment: @Rahul That´s completely different. In this case you would fetch all elements that have any of the three values.

Answer (score 0):

Not precisely. You would need to do something like

```
var result = context.table.Include(x => x.table2).Where(qx);
```

because `q1`, `q2` etc. are already expressions compatible with what `.Where()` expects.

Answer (score 0):

`IQueryable.Where` accepts an `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>`, you can do something like this:

```
Expression<Func<SourceType, bool>> qx = q => false;
Expression<Func<SourceType, bool>> q1 = q => q.x == "something";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to note before my answer, you can't declare `qx` like this:

`var qx;`

because the compiler won't resolve a type right away.
And what you are asking is possible if you specify the type that q is.

```
Func<type, bool> q1 = (type q) => q.x == "something";
Func<type, bool> q2 = (type q) => q.x == "something2";
Func<type, bool> q3 = (type q) => q.x == "something3";

Func<type, bool> qx = q3; //this needs a value (if x and y are false)
if(x)
{
   qx = q1;
}
if(y)
{
   qx = q2;
}

var result = context.table.Include(x => x.table2).Where(qx);
```

Comment: The `var` issue is my fault. Initially it was declared inside the `if` blocks, making it out of scope for the last line, so I moved it Up. I don't use `var` very often.

Comment: You should explicity write the type, its best practice. `var` is really meant for anonymous classes and querys, although nothing wrong with it if you can read it

Comment: I totally agree. That's why I don't use it often.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to need a query where the actual condition is provided at runtime. Just use a [`Predicate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1):

```
Predicate<MyType> predicate;
if(x)
{
    predicate = q => q.x == "something";
}
else if(y)
{
    predicate = q => q.x == "something2";
}
else
    predicate = q => q.x == "something3";
var result = context.table.Include(x => x.table2).where(predicate);
```